# I forgot how to call this in vim

Tags: vim

`nnoremap <C-n> :call NumberToggle()<cr>`

I tried ctrl-n and it doesn't work. I've completely forgotten how to call this and google hasn't been my friend tonight.

Comment: By `NumberToggle()` you mean `set nu` and `set nonu`?

Comment: It's a custom function that I wrote. It's not relavent to the question. I just need to know how to call it. I imagine it's `nnoremap <C-n>` telling me how to do it, but it appears that doesn't mean `ctrl-n`

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding it, you can call `nmap <C-n>` to find what is <C-n> eventually mapped to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapping definition looks fine and should work in *normal mode*. If `<C-n>` doesn't work, the mapping probably has been overwritten. Check with

```
:verbose nmap <C-n>
```

If this yields a different plugin / configuration, you have to change either (e.g. to `<Leader>n`) to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you. It appears that a plugin was conflicting. Thanks for the help!